# Jquery focusin and validating data not woking on php project

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php project with some php files.
I am triying to validate form data with jquery but its not working.
This is my code. The file is index.php.
I want to clear text input when clicked and validate input text with text and spaces.Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Criar</title>
    <link href="CSS_Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="JS/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include 'menu.php';
    ?>
    <h1>Criar novo registo</h1>

    <form class="criar">
        <label class="criar">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" id="input_nome" name="nome" value="Insira">
        <br>
        <label class="criar">Apelido</label>
        <input type="text" id="input_apelido" name="apelido" value="Insira">
        <br>
        <label class="criar">Telefone</label>
        <input type="texto" id="input_telefone" name="tele" value="Insira">
        <br>
        <label class="criar">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="input_email" name="email">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="botao" name="criar" value="Criar">
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

         $("#input_nome").focusin(function()){
            $(this).value=' ';   
         });


        $("#input_nome").focusout(function(){

            var v=$("#input_name").val();
            var l=$("#input_name").val().length;
            var regex= /^[\S][\w\]+$/;
            if (v.match(regex)){
                window.alert("Got it");
            }
        });
     });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To empty the input change it `$(this).value=' ';` to  `$(this).val(' ');`

Comment: What do you want to do in the focusout validation?

Comment: In the focus out I want to check is a space then any word and if so make a window alert saying got it.

Comment: I have changet it before and dindt work too

Comment: Do you want to check if it starts with a space char (' ')?

Comment: Yes, first character CANT be space but be letter.

Answer (score 0):

For test I have put a console.log after document ready function and it work.
So for now I guess something must be wrong with the code.
Thanks for the help.
I will go more deep o this.